# How to bypass HTTPS SSL certificate verification in Android using Kotlin and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ssl, https

I'm trying to send a POST request to node server from an Android client.
I'm getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError error while Creating okhttpClient that suppose to bypass Android's SSL certificate verification process

This is my code:

```
object RetrofitServiceBuilder {

    private val interceptor = run {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.apply {
            httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
    }

    private val trustAllCerts : Array<X509TrustManager> = arrayOf(object : X509TrustManager {
        @Throws(CertificateException::class)
        override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate>? = null
        override fun checkClientTrusted(certs: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}
        override fun checkServerTrusted(certs: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}
    })

    private val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS").apply {
        init(null, trustAllCerts,  SecureRandom())
    }

    private val hostNameVerifier : HostnameVerifier =
        HostnameVerifier { hostname, session -> true; }

    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            //This is the part where i get the error
        .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory, trustAllCerts[0])
        .hostnameVerifier(hostNameVerifier)
        .build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://xx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T {
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to correctly write this certificate verification bypass code?

Comment: Note that apps that have implemented what you desire ("bypass Android's SSL certificate verification process") have been banned from the Play Store. You might want to check the policies of your desired app distribution channel, or you might want to find ways to not do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you mean setting `clearTextTraffic` to `true` in `AndroidManifest.xml` is also not allowed by playstore now? 

Comment: @mehulbisht: That is not what the asker is trying to do. Allowing cleartext traffic means "support HTTP". What the asker is trying to do is "support HTTPS with invalid certificates and invalid hostnames". [The automated Play Store checks are going to take issue with that](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426?hl=en), as countless developers have discovered (search for "insecure hostnameverifier" on your favorite search engine).

Comment: I am using it for development not for distribution.